# Laravel vue сохранение файла на сервере

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Возникла проблема при сохранение файла на сервере. 
Есть vue компонент:

```
<form @submit.prevent="addNews" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input ref="image" type="file" @change="processFile">
    ...
</form>

methods: {
    processFile(event) {
        this.img = event.target.files[0];
        console.log(this.img); // В консоли картинка распознаётся со всеми параметрами как надо
    },
    addNews() {
        axios.post('/news/create', {
            title: this.title,
            img: this.img, // Здесь уходит пустой массив? O_o (подсмотрел в консоли)
            description: this.description,
            article: this.article,
        })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
            })
    }
```

Всё приходит на сервер кроме картинки (приходит пустой массив вместо него). В чем может быть проблема?

Увидел что используют такую конструкцию:

```
let form = new FormData();
form.append('img', this.img);
```

Стоит ли переделывать всё под эту конструкцию? (проверил - работает)

```
let form = new FormData();
form.append('title', this.title);
form.append('description', this.description);
form.append('article', this.article);
form.append('img', this.img);

axios.post('/news/create', form)
```

Или же есть более простой способ в решении моей проблемы?

Зачем создавать новую форму и передавать параметры из старой формы? Возможно необходимы дополнительные параметры для формы?

Comment: Несколько я знаю `FormData()` это самый адекватный спосок отправить бинарные данные(картинку или фаил) на сервер, с помощью Ajax.

Comment: @ДмитрийМирошниченко, а почему нужно передавать параметры из одной формы в другую?

Comment: В данном случае это не новая форма, а экземпляр данных из формы. FormData сама умеет данные извлекать из формы, для этого нужно в конструктор передать выборку с элементом формы. Если у Вас в форме все значения и именная полей Вам подходят можете так и поступить.

Answer (score 0):

При создании объекта *FormData*, передайте в качестве аргумента объект существующей формы.

```
let form = new FormData(this);
axios.post('/news/create', form);
```